# Union of closure of two set and closure of union of two sets: what's wrong in general case

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I know that there are many question with the same title here on MSE, but I still confuse with my approach to solve this, so I still put it here for proof verification and I do want to know is there anything wrong with part b and why it fails in part c, in the case of arbitrary family of subsets.

> b. $\overline{A\cup B}=\bar{A}\cup \bar{B}$
>
> Let $x\in \overline{A\cup B}$ then for any open neighborhood $U_x$; $U_x\cap \left(A\cup B\right)\neq \emptyset$.
>
> Then $U_x\cap A\neq \emptyset$ or $U_x\cap B\neq \emptyset$ hence $x\in \bar{A}$ or $x\in \bar{B}\Rightarrow x\in \bar{A}\cup \bar{B}$.
> So $\overline{A\cup B}\subseteq \bar{A}\cup \bar{B}$.
>
> Similarly, if $x\in \bar{A}\cup \bar{B}$ then $x\in \bar A$ or $x\in \bar B$. Thus for any open neigborhood $U_x$ of x: $U_x\cap A \neq \emptyset$ or $U_x\cap B\neq \emptyset$
>
> $\Rightarrow U_x\cap (A\cup B)\neq \emptyset$ or $x\in \overline{A\cup B}$.
>
> Therefore, $\overline{A}\cup \overline{B}\subseteq \overline{A\cup B}$.  So $\overline{A\cup B} = \overline{A}\cup \overline{B}$.
>
> c. $\overline{\cup_\alpha A_\alpha}=\cup_\alpha\overline{A_\alpha}$
> For this part, the same method applies here.
>
> If x belongs to the LHS, then any neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$ intersects $\cup_\alpha A_\alpha$ equivalently $U_x$ intersects one of $A_\alpha$ for some $\alpha$ therefore $x\in \overline{A_\alpha}$ and hence $x\in \cup_\alpha\overline{A_\alpha}\Rightarrow \overline{\cup_\alpha A_\alpha}\subseteq \cup_\alpha\overline{A_\alpha}$.
>
> If $x$ belongs to the RHS then $x\in \overline{A_\alpha}$ for some $\alpha$. So for any neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$: $U_x\cap A_\alpha\neq \emptyset\Rightarrow U_x\cap (\cup A_\alpha) \neq \emptyset$ so $x\in \overline{\cup_\alpha A_\alpha}\Rightarrow \cup_\alpha \overline{A_\alpha}\subseteq \overline{\cup_\alpha A_\alpha}$
>
> Therefore $\overline{\cup_\alpha A_\alpha}=\cup_\alpha\overline{A_\alpha}$.

Please explain to me. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Riemann even if this $\alpha$ may depend on $x$ but in the end we still have $U_x\cap (\cup A_\alpha)\neq \emptyset$?

Comment: The problem is not that $\alpha$ depends on $x$ but that (for fixed $x$) it depends on $U$ (which btw there is no reason to denote by $U_x$). You proof in b is flawed at the same point: " for any open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ [...] $U\cap A\neq \emptyset$ or $U\cap B\neq \emptyset$ hence $x\in \bar{A}$ or $x\in \bar{B}$"

Comment: $(\forall x)(P(x)\lor Q(x))$ is _not_ (in general) equivalent to $(\forall x)P(x)\lor(\forall x)Q(x)$. Here you can fix the argument in the finite case: suppose the opposite, that there is a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ not intersecting $A$ and a neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ not intersecting $B$, then $U\cap V$ is a new neighborhood of $x$ not intersecting $A\cup B$. Here you use the fact that _finite_ intersection of open sets is open. The argument doesn't work in the infinite case precisely because an _infinite_ intersection of open sets need not be open.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks for correction and sorry for my mistake. So for each $U$ there may be different $A_\alpha$ intersecting with it, and there's no guarantee for existence of a 'fixed' $\alpha$ s.t $A_\alpha$ intersects for any neighborhood $U$ of $x$.

Comment: @AnneBauval Can you explain in more details that $U\cap (A\cup B)\neq \emptyset\Rightarrow U\cap A\neq \emptyset \ \text{or} U\cap B\neq \emptyset$ is flawed?

Comment: It is not that derivation which is flawed, but the next one, as pointed in my first comment above. I edited a detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

The b part is fine.

I recommend you to write c with quantifiers to see it clearly.
The wrong content is $\subset$. I name $\mathcal{T}$ the topology of your space.

Let be $x\in \overline{\cup_\alpha A_\alpha} \Rightarrow \forall U \in \mathcal{T}, x \in U : U \cap (\cup_\alpha A_\alpha) \neq \emptyset \Rightarrow \forall U \in \mathcal{T}, x\in U \, \, \exists \alpha \, : U \cap A_\alpha \neq \emptyset $.
Due to the order of the quantifiers, that is not equivalent to $\exists \alpha \, \forall U \in \mathcal{T}, x\in U : U \cap A_\alpha \neq \emptyset $, what it does mean be in the clausure of some $A_\alpha$, so you cannot deduce that.

In fact, you can think in the sets $(-1+1/n,1-1/n)$ with $n\in \mathbb{N}, n\geq 2$. We have that
$$\bigcup_{n\geq 2} (-1+1/n,1-1/n) = (-1,1)$$
so
$$\overline{\bigcup_{n\geq 2} (-1+1/n,1-1/n)}  = \overline{(-1,1)}=[-1,1]$$
but
$$\bigcup_{n\geq 2} \overline{(-1+1/n,1-1/n)} = \bigcup_{n\geq 2} [-1+1/n,1-1/n] = (-1,1)$$
and you have a counterexample.

- List item

Answer (score 1):

- Part b is already flawed (I mean: the result is true but your proof is wrong).

  - Your proof in b is flawed at the following point: "for any open neighborhood $U$
    of $x$ [...] $U∩A≠∅$ or $U∩B≠∅$ *hence* $x∈\bar A$ or $x∈\bar B$" is not correct because, denoting by $O_x$ the set of open neighborhoods of $x$, from $$\forall U\in O_x(U∩A≠∅\lor U∩B≠∅)$$ alone, you cannot logically derive $$(\forall U\in O_x,U∩A≠∅)\lor (\forall U\in O_x,U∩B≠∅).$$
  - To summarize, you are pretending that
    $\forall U,(P(U)\lor Q(U))$ implies $(\forall U,P(U))\lor(\forall U,Q(U)),$ which is a (frequent) mistake. For instance:
    $$[\forall t,(t=\varnothing\lor t\ne\varnothing)]\not\Rightarrow[[(\forall t,t=\varnothing)\lor(\forall t,t\ne\varnothing)].$$
  - The proof for b can be repaired, as you can see in many posts on this site.
- The flaw in your similar part c is perhaps more blatant because there, the result itself is false.

  - The mistake is at the following point: "any neighborhood $U$ of $x$ [...] intersects one of $A_\alpha$ for some $\alpha$ *therefore* $x\in \overline{A_\alpha}$". The problem is that $α$ depends on $U.$
  - Here you are pretending that $\forall U\exists\alpha,P(U,\alpha)$ implies $\exists\alpha\forall U, P(U,\alpha).$ This is the same kind of mistake as in b. The existential quantifier $\exists$ is like an "infinite $\lor$", and this analogous claim is similarly wrong. For instance:
    $$[\forall s\exists t(t=s)]\not\Rightarrow[\exists t\forall s(t=s)].$$
    (Think also to the difference between continuity and uniform continuity, in the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition.)
  - The proof of c cannot be repaired, as you already know (since this is the reason of your post), and there are counterexamples in many posts on this site.

Comment: No. that's not my intention. For part b, my idea is $U\cap(A\cup B) = (U\cap A) \cup (U\cap B)$. Since the union is not an empty set then one of these two set should not be an empty set.

Comment: Of course, but once again: the flaw is not there but just after. I just detailed that even more in my answer.